# How to access a variable outside the .then scope in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, promise, node-oracledb

Need some help on this.

So, it is like I have one function from where I am returning a Promise(q based). Now inside a second function, I am calling that function by chaining on that using .then, now inside this .then I have written a method for some manipulation and based on that I am expecting a value. After that returned value, outside of the .then, my DB connection code get's started. So now the problem is that I am not able to access that variable value which is getting returned by the method inside the .then thus my DB returning data is incorrect.

In code it looks like this.

```
getSomeWarehouseData(){
return defer.promise
}

getOracleData(){

   getSomeWarehouseData().then(function(returnedValue){
      ***some data manipulation

      function getCustomizedDetails(){
      return data;
      }

      custom_data = getCustomizedDetails()

})//.then scope ends

// Unable to access custom_data outside the .then 

**** console.log(custom_data)// undefined****

**Oracle Code getting Started****

oracledb.getConnection(
{
***connection settings
},
function(err, connection)
{

***inside here I need to access the custom_data variable*** which is not accessible currently.

})

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use arrow function (`(err, connection) => {}`) instead of `function(err, connection)`?

Comment: @MaxAmorim, the variable is not accessible outside the .then closure so even after changing the function to arrow function, it will not work. So if you see my code sample provided here, I cannot access the variable when right from the place where I have written **Oracle Code getting Started****

Comment: You don't show on your code where you declare `custom_data`. You should declare outside of the `getSomeWarehouseData()`, manipulate inside of the `then()` statement, and re-use it on `oracledb.getConnection()`

Comment: @MaxAmorim, thanks for your comment, I have done the same thing, I have declared it inside the getOracleData() function and using it inside the .then however it is not accessible outside the .then even though it's still inside the getOracleData() function. So that means, that variable data is not accessible outside the .then({ }) chain.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'not accessible'? It's `undefined`? There's any specific reason why you didn't placed `oracledb.getConnection` inside of `then`? Then you would ensure data to the function.

Comment: @MaxAmorim, Yes I meant to say undefined, and when I am placing the oracledb.getConnection inside .then then DB query is not getting fired thus it simply didn't fetch result from the DB. So I thought of not putting it inside the .then

Comment: Cool, can you share the `getSomeWarehouseData()` code? Also, can you place a `console.log(custom_data)` just after `custom_data = getCustomizedDetails()` and tell me if there's any value on console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212351/discussion-between-sambhav-and-max-amorim).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the code with the async Terminology of javascript. Use your second function inside `getOracleData` with in `then`.

```
getSomeWarehouseData() {
return defer.promise;};

getOracleData() {

getSomeWarehouseData().then(function (returnedValue) {
        // **
        // * some data manipulation

        function getCustomizedDetails() {
            return data;
        }

        custom_data = getCustomizedDetails();

        oracledb.getConnection({
            // **
            // * connection settings
        },
        function (err, connection) {

            // **
            // * inside here I need to access the custom_data variable ** * which is not accessible currently.
            console.log(custom_data);

        });

    }) ;//.then scope ends

    // Unable to access custom_data outside the .then 

    // **
    // ** console.log(custom_data) // undefined****

    // **
    // Oracle Code getting Started ** *};
```

Comment: this was my first approach, however, the problem with this is that the DB connection is not getting established thus probably the connection.execute is getting failed, though I didn't check that.

Comment: Also, when I trying to call getOracleData so as to get the sqlResponse from it, the custom_data variable which I bind it in the query is not available to me and the query column is returning it as "undefined". I am just calling the getOracleData by chaining .then on its result like getOracleData(paramA, paramB).then(function(sqlresponse){ processing the result here whcich shows the data not available and  coming as undefined}